# Time difference between chrome / edge on windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, timezone, microsoft-edge

I get TZ difference on windows 10 between Chrome and Edge. 
When I run this code in the console:

```
> var date = new Date(2013, 2, 29, 1, 0, 0, 0);
> date
```

This will be the output when running in on Edge

```
> [date] Fri Mar 29 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
```

While This will be the output on Chrome:

```
> [date] Fri Mar 29 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

It seems that in Chrome it is recognise as DST but in Edge it doesn’t, which is correct.
([Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fSnk.png))

If I turn off the “Adjust for day light saving time automatically” configuration - Chrome date becomes the same. ([image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfvno.png))

Someone, can explain why? and how to get the correct TZ in chrome in any "Date and Time" configuration?

Edge version: 20.10240.16384.0
Chrome version: 56.0.2924.75 (64-bit)

Comment: Flagged as off topic because this is not related to programming, but to general software configuration.

Comment: @nicovank - I disagree.  This is clearly a browser issue, and there is code in the screenshot.  Noam - please put the code directly in the issue as well.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson

Comment: It is very strange behaviour and surely related to programming IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed appears to be a bug.

The [TZ Database shows](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2016j/asia#L1379-L1395):

```
# As of 2013, DST starts at 02:00 on the Friday before the last Sunday
# in March.  DST ends at 02:00 on the last Sunday of October.

# Rule  NAME  FROM  TO   TYPE  IN   ON       AT    SAVE  LETTER/S
Rule    Zion  2013  max  -     Mar  Fri>=23  2:00  1:00  D
Rule    Zion  2013  max  -     Oct  lastSun  2:00  0     S

# Zone    NAME            GMTOFF    RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Asia/Jerusalem    2:20:54   -       LMT     1880
                          2:20:40   -       JMT     1918    # Jerusalem Mean Time?
                          2:00      Zion    I%sT
```

Therefore, in 2013, DST should have started on the Friday before the last Sunday in March, which was March 29.  (The previous Friday was March 22, which doesn't meet the `Fri>=23` rule in the time zone data.)  [This is date is also corroborated by timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/israel/jerusalem?year=2013).

Windows appears to have this data correct.  Examining the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Israel Standard Time\Dynamic DST
```

[image: Windows Registry]

The last part I highlighted in green is the DST start date.

```
00 00 = Year        (ignored)
03 00 = Month       (March)
05 00 = Day of week (Friday)
05 00 = Day number  (5 = last)
02 00 = Hour        (02:00)
00 00 = Minute
00 00 = Second
00 00 = Millisecond
```

So both the Windows and the IANA data are pointing at the same date.  Yet somehow Chrome is getting it wrong.

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

I also tested FireFox, which also appears to be getting it wrong:

[image: FireFox Screenshot]

I can also reproduce these results in Node.js.

But yes, Edge is getting it correct:

[image: Edge Screenshot]

Do note that the browsers also differ in which direction they adjust a local time that falls into the "gap" created by the spring-forward transition.  This is expected, and [is being worked on in for a future version the of ECMAScript spec](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/778).

I don't work on the actual implementation within these browsers, but my understanding is that both Chrome, Node, and FireFox rely on [ICU](http://icu-project.org/) for their time zone internals.  <s>My guess is that it is an ICU bug that is being exposed here.</s> ***Update:*** It appears to be a bug in the Microsoft C/C++ Runtime.  I'm working on getting it to the right folks.

As far as what to do about it - if accurate historical time zone data is essential to your application, I strongly suggest you not rely on the environment to provide it, but bring it yourself using one of the libraries I listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824), such as [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone) (which I help maintain).

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson for the detailed answer!
Two comments: 
1. Should we open a bug for Chrome and FF?
2. The specific date I tested wasn't a random one. It is used by this [library](https://github.com/HenningM/jstimezonedetect). I'll mention this issue also there

Comment: Chrome bug reported [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687751), FireFox bug reported [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1335818).  Thanks!